Considering 3 possible sump pump backup solutions
I'm trying to decide on which of three possible paths to take for building a backup system for my two sump pumps. Here's the use case based on a flood event from last year.

My property has a high water table, 5-7 feet.
My house is at the bottom of a slight hill with 3 house between me and the base of a mesa. There are no sidewalks or gutters on the road. All the neighbors drain their rain gutters 6-10 feet from their house or to their property line (so the neighbor has to deal with the extra runoff.)
It was an unusually wet spring, so the ground was saturated.
A supercell rain storm hit at the end of June, breaking a 141 year record for rainfall. It rained the proverbial cats and dogs for 2+ hours.

All this combined to create a good sized creek through my property. The sump pumps were running full time and couldn't keep up with the influx of water to my basement. If I hadn't been home to set up an ad hoc syphon to the sewer drain it's likely there would have been 4-6" of standing water in my basement. Worse if the power had gone out, which happens more and more frequently these days. Recently, the power was out for three days and I had to manually cycle the sump pumps with a gasoline powered generator.
At an engineering company's recommendation after assessing the damage, I've installed a spillway and 80' of 12" culvert that should divert the bulk of the water from such a storm around my house.
Here's what I'm considering.

Battery backup system for the existing electric pumps. This system would need an automatic power transfer switch, inverter, 12V marine battery, and battery charger.

Battery backup system using a bilge pump, 12V marine battery, and battery charger.

Water powered backup pump.


Option 3 is the most desirable as it will cover short and long power outages along with pump failures. However, it is the most expensive given the plumbing involved (unless I can find a pump that performs off the pressure from a 1/2" PLEX line.
Option 2 is more straightforward and seems the most cost effective, but I have no experience with bilge pumps - their reliability, performance, etc.
Option 1 seems fairly robust, but I read of problems with battery safety and maintenance.
What am I missing with either of these options?

Can the water powered pumps keep up with the inflow?   You don't know because 141 years and you did some diverting work so you don't know what flow to plan for.  Tough decision.  Would you otherwise have a generator?  Do you go away far from home often?   All rhetorical questions ...  The answers will help you decide.

Note if you get the water powered pump it needs it's own discharge pipe.  A lot of YouTube demos including professional plumbers share the existing pipe. Don't.  Follow the instructions.

Quite a few places do not allow neighbours to dump water onto your land.  Check with local/town.

If you are planning to endure a long-term power outage, consider the size battery needed. A Rule 23 l/m (360 GPH) pump draws about 2.5 A, Rule 2000, 126 l/m (2000 GPH) about 9 A. A 100 A-h marine battery would run the smaller for ~30 hours, the larger for ~8 hours (leaving ~25% capacity, so as not to destroy the battery from excessively deep discharge). There is an advantage in immediate action, without switchover, but also consider a solar panel or small generator to keep the battery charged.

You mention a hill. Is there any point on your land where the ground level is below your basement floor level

@VtC: "What am I missing" is similar to "What are the pros/cons" and seems like a reasonable question.

Option 3. A venturi pump can operate Just Fine off normal house pressure and volume. It won't move as much water per minute as an electric powered pump can, but I have seen a cheap one hooked to garden hose on both ends move 4000 cubic feet of water in about a week (plus however many it was consuming to drive it). As a fallback until you can get power and/or a replacement pump, it will probably suffice, and will not suffer from running out of battery or fuel.

I went with option 3 and added a Tesla PowerWall 3 to the mix. The PowerWall should handle the power-to-the-mechanical-sump-pump issue and the water powered sump pumps should handle any mechanical failures with the primary pumps.

First, most likely 1 pump is doing most/all of the heavy lifting here.  Simply because its "start" setpoint is lower than the other one's, so it starts before the other one would.
Second, DC-coupling the system is always simpler than having an inverter, if you can develop confidence in quality DC pumps. (and yeah, marine is the place to go for that).
Now your option 1 with the automatic transfer switch, everyone always overthinks that.  You don't need an ATS because you can just run it off the inverter all the time.  Think about it. You're already going to have a battery charger on that battery 24x7 to keep it topped up.   All you need to do is select a somewhat higher capacity charger which has enough output to cover the sump pump's power requirements plus a bit.  When the pump starts, it will drop the battery voltage slightly which will cause the charger to increase its amp output to hold charging voltage.  Thus the pump will be powered directly off the charger.  This is the normal way DC systems like your car's alternator work.
Yes, there will be some loss in the AC/DC/AC transition, but that's cheaper than an ATS and associated failure risk.
When a power failure happens, and you get there and find the pump has been active, you hook up and start a generator, and hook it to the battery charger, and it tops up the battery.  And if the pump is 100% duty cycle during that time, it still tops up the battery because the charger is a bit bigger than the pump draw.
That's really it, it's not more complicated than that.
Since you apparently need both pumps to keep up, you might think about replicating the DC backup for both pumps. I don't see a point to having only 1/2 pumps on DC if it means it can't keep up and will flood the basement anyway.

This is a really interesting alternative. Certainly, the more points of failure I can take out of the solution the better. What would I need to know to figure out the specs for a "somewhat higher capacity charger"? And yes, as was mentioned with another comment, the backup system (DC) needs to mirror the primary (AC) rather than tap into the same discharge line. It's possible I'll need 4 pumps working at full capacity. I haven't ruled out a second backup system using city water pressure.

"somewhat higher capacity" would be somewhat more than the pump draw.  So the charger continues charging even with the pump running.  How much more depends on how quick you want to recover the battery when you start your generator. Assuming long-term power outage. @5280Angel

Option 4: gas or propane powered water pump with electric starter coupled to a level detector.
It's a bit expensive, and you can't run it inside due to exhaust so you would need to build a small enclosure outside, but it will run without mains power, and it only uses the battery for starting so it will last a long time.
Option 5: self starting siphon
This needs a bit of work, but it will run for a long time on a small 12V battery.
First you need a siphon, from your sump to somewhere lower in altitude where you will dump the water, with large enough pipe to take care of the flow.
Then you put a motorized valve at the lowest point (the exit) and a small pump to fill the pipe with water.
Starting state: valve closed. When the water level detector senses the sump is filling, it runs the water pump for a set time to fill the siphon with water, then opens the valve at the end of the pipe.
This is more complicated as it needs a bit of brains, but it will use almost no power.
